# php script on duplicate update function

Tags: php

am doing an online admission system as my project. 
Am having issues with the on duplicate query..
this is my php script.

```
$save="INSERT INTO student_reg (Reg_number,username,password,surname,fname,mname,sex,address,city,state,country,
     Email,Prog_code,dept_code)
     VALUES('".$_SESSION['random']."','".$_SESSION['uname']."','".$_SESSION['password']."','".$_SESSION['sname']."',
       '".$_SESSION['fname']."','".$_SESSION['mname']."','".$_SESSION['sex']."',
                         '".$_SESSION['address']."','".$_SESSION['city']."','".$_SESSION['state']."','".$_SESSION['country']."',

                     '".$_SESSION['email']."','".$_SESSION['progcode']."','".$_SESSION['deptcode']."')

                ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                username= '" . $_POST['username'] . "',password = '" . $_POST['password'] . "',
surname='" . $_POST['surname'] . "',fname = '" . $_POST['fname'] . "',mname = '" . $_POST['mname'] . "',
sex = '" . $_POST['sex'] . "',address= '" . $_POST['address'] . "',
city= '" . $_POST['city'] . "',state= '" . $_POST['state'] . "',country = '" . $_POST['country'] . "',
Email = '" . $_POST['email'] . "',Prog_code = '" . $_SESSION['progcode'] . "',dept_code = '".$_SESSION['deptcode']."'


 ";

 $result=mysql_query($save)or die(mysql_error());

        if($save==TRUE){
        echo"save";

        }
        else{
        echo "not saved";
        }
```

The s_session(random) is used to automatically assign
Reg_numbers to students after their form has been saved and the value is stored in a unique field in d database called reg_number.

When I execute the query,the insert option works perfectly
but the update doesn't work rather,it kips inserting a new record over and over again into the database once the submit button is click..

Comment: *..., it skips inserting a new record...* Isn't that exactly what you wanted by using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: I think it would update old case if $_SESSION['random'] is already in db. Mysql is deprecated and you should use PDO or MySQLi. Also that is a very dangerous query, without escaping $_POST values at all.

Comment: It doesn't skip the insert statement,it skips the update part,becos new records are always inserted when I click the submit button. .

Comment: It doesn't skip the insert record part but rather it doesn't update the current record becos everytime I click the submit button,I get a new record inserted

Comment: Learn about double quoted string and variable parsing to get a cleaner code, or better learn MySQLi extension and parameter binding. It hurts my eyes just to look at your code.